# ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement Oracle error

Tags: oracle

I am new to oracle. I am trying to run a oracle script using HPDMA tool which in turn invokes table creation scripts that create the table schemas. I am getting the following error in one of the scripts:

```
Table MODEL
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
ORA-06512: at line 46
```

The below is the table creation script:

```
SET DEFINE OFF;
Prompt Table MODEL;

declare
    l_count int;
begin

    select  count(*)
    into    l_count
    from    all_tables
    where   owner = 'PORTAL'
    and     table_name = 'MODEL';

     if l_count = 0 then
     execute immediate 
        'CREATE TABLE PORTAL.MODEL
            (
              CONFIG_ID     NUMBER,
              CONFIG_NAME   VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
              CONFIG_VALUE  VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
              MODEL_TYPE    VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
              CONFIG_TYPE   VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
              IS_ACTIVE     CHAR(1 BYTE),
              CREATED_BY    VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
              CREATED_ON    DATE,
              UPDATED_BY    VARCHAR2(80 BYTE),
              UPDATED_ON    DATE,
              DESCRIPTION   VARCHAR2(500 BYTE)
            )

            TABLESPACE PORTAL_DATA
            PCTUSED    0
            PCTFREE    10
            INITRANS   1
            MAXTRANS   255
            STORAGE    (
                        INITIAL          64K
                        NEXT             1M
                        MINEXTENTS       1
                        MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
                        PCTINCREASE      0
                        BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
                       )
            LOGGING 
            NOCOMPRESS 
            NOCACHE
            NOPARALLEL
            MONITORING';
            execute immediate 'Prompt Non-Foreign Key Constraints on Table MODEL';
            execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE PORTAL.MODEL ADD (
              CONSTRAINT MODEL_CONFIG_ID_PK
              PRIMARY KEY
              (CONFIG_ID)
              ENABLE VALIDATE)';


            execute immediate 'GRANT INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON PORTAL.MODEL TO user1';

            execute immediate 'GRANT INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON PORTAL.MODEL TO user2';

            execute immediate 'GRANT SELECT ON PORTAL.MODEL TO user3';
 end if;

end;
/
```

Line 46 has NOCACHE statement. I didn't have this error when I ran the script on a different database.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The error is reported against line 46 - which is referring to that line in the PL/SQL block, not in the overall script. Line 46 of the PL/SQL block is:

```
execute immediate 'Prompt Non-Foreign Key Constraints on Table MODEL';
```

[`PROMPT` is a SQL*Plus client command.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve032.htm#SQPUG052) It is, as the error says, not a SQL command. It isn't valid in the SQL context that `execute immediate` gives you, which is running on the server and has nothing to do with the client. (You could run that block via a scheduled job, for instance, with no client interaction at all).

You need to remove that line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I didn't face this error when I deployed to a different database. What might be the reason for failure on this particular instance?

Comment: And how did your determine the line that gave error? Can you please share it so that it'll be helpful for me later. Thanks!

Comment: The prompt command will fail on any instance. Are you sure that line existed before? Or it is possible the error just wasn't noticed; depending on how it was run, there could be a .login or .glogin setup script that set `whenever sqlerror` differently, for instance - which might affect the overall script success/failure. Worth checking the old logs maybe. In this case the table was created, but presumably the primary key was not added?

Comment: As for the line number, I know the error is reported within the PL/SQL block with `declare` as line 1. If the `nocache` was a problem the error would have referre to line 12, the line number of the previous `execute immediate`.